# How to find descendant elements of a selected element or ElementHandle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

In other browser automation frameworks there tends to be a "find" method that allows the user to find all decedents of a given element that match the selector for example:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_traversing_descendants.asp

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div").find("span");
});
```

The above method returns all elements that match `span` descending from the given `div`.

If I have an ElementHandle, is there a way I could find all dependents that match a given selector using puppeteer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`elementHandle.$`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#elementhandleselector) function. Quote from the docs:

> The method runs `element.querySelector` within the page. If no element matches the selector, the return value resolves to `null`.

**Code sample:**

```js
const elementHandle = await page.$('div');
const elementInsideHandle = await elementHandle.$('span');
```

If you want to query multiple elements, there is also the [`$$`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.15.0/docs/api.md#elementhandleselector) function to run `element.querySelectorAll` inside the page.